# jquery ignore child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

hi i have a div tag with nested divs as shown below

```
<div class="friendRequestMenu" id="friendRequestMenu">
    <div class="toolbarTitle">
        <span>Friend Requests</span> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hyperlink">Find Friends</a>
    </div>
    <div id="friendRequestData">
        <!-- put div class=requestli to see a block-->
        <div class="no-request">
            No New Friend Requests
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div class="see-all-requests">
                See All Requests
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('*').each(function() {   /getting all elements in document
  // do something for all elements except the div tag above
});
```

i want the code to apply for everything except for the div tag and its children, i know i can get all the id's and add an exception , but i want to do that with only the parent tag
thanks
EDIT:

hi this is exactly what i want to do

```
$(document.body).find('*:not(#friendRequestMenu):not(#friendRequestMenu *)').each(function () {

    var clientWidth = $(window).width();
    var clientHeight = $(window).height();
    var heightPercent = ($(this).height() / clientHeight) * 100;
    var widthPercent = ($(this).width() / clientWidth) * 100;
    $(this).css('height', heightPercent.toString());
    $(this).css('width', widthPercent.toString());


    });
```

but i want to ignore some elements, as you can see the selector part code isnt working for me

Comment: If you take out the div tags and their children, then there's nothing left.

Comment: I would suggest you reconsider if using the `*` selector is a good idea. Maybe what you want to do is possible without iterating over the zillion elements that make up a production web page?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('*:not(#friendRequestMenu):not(#friendRequestMenu *)').each(...);
```

Using the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector should handle this nicely.

Comment: hi i tried his, but the child elements are still affected, basically im trying to change the css of a lot of elements, but i dont want those particular elements and their children to change, without having to specify all those children

Comment: @anonymouslyAnonymous: Keep in mind that the C in CSS stands for cascade. Any fonts, colors, etc. applied to parents will traverse to the children as well...

Comment: @anonymouslyAnonymous: Please see [this demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8LUVf/)

Comment: hi this is basically my code  $(document.body).find('*:not(#friendRequestMenu):not(#friendRequestMenu *)').each(function () {
        var clientWidth = $(window).width();
        var clientHeight = $(window).height();
        var heightPercent = ($(this).height() / clientHeight) * 100;
        var widthPercent = ($(this).width() / clientWidth) * 100;
        $(this).css('height', heightPercent.toString());
        $(this).css('width', widthPercent.toString());
        }

        });

Answer (score 0):

The simplest forms are as follows:

```
$(':not(#friendRequestMenu, #friendRequestMenu *)').each(...);
```

and

```
$('*').not('#friendRequestMenu, #friendRequestMenu *');
```

The second version is likely to be more efficient as I don't believe that the browser's native implementation of `querySelectorAll` supports `:not(...)`. Don't bother optimizing unless you have an issue with how long the query takes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('*').not("#friendRequestMenu, #friendRequestMenu *").each(function(){
  //do something here
});
```

Comment: should be `.not('#friendRequestMenu, #friendRequestMenu *')`

Comment: This will ignore `#friendRequestMenu` but not its children.

Comment: hi the code does not ignore the child elements thanks for the help anyways